Cloudformation aws - adding a dynamic uuid based on the stack id
Hey I'm working with cloudformation template and i have this policy:
"yagelPolicy": {
   "Type":"AWS::IAM::Policy",
   "Properties":{
      "PolicyName":{
         "Fn::If":[
            "CreateDynamicResource",
            {
               "Fn::Sub":"yagel${AWS::AccountId}-${StackUUID}"
            },
            {
               "Fn::Sub":"yagel${AWS::AccountId}"
            }
         ]
      },
      "PolicyDocument":{
         "Version":"2012-10-17",
         "Statement":[
            {
               "Sid":"scapolicyallowtag",
               "Action":[
                  "sts:TagSession"
               ],
               "Resource":"*",
               "Effect":"Allow"
            },
            {
               "Sid":"AssumeCustomerRole",
               "Action":[
                  "sts:AssumeRole",
                  "sts:SetSourceIdentity"
               ],
               "Resource":"*",
               "Effect":"Allow"
            },
            {
               "Sid":"scapolicyaccountpermissions",
               "Action":[
                  "iam:UpdateAssumeRolePolicy",
                  "iam:ListSAMLProviders",
                  "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                  "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                  "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                  "iam:GetSAMLProvider",
                  "iam:GetRole",
                  "iam:ListRoles",
                  "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                  "iam:GetPolicy",
                  "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                  "iam:ListRolePolicies"
               ],
               "Resource":"*",
               "Effect":"Allow"
            }
         ]
      },
      "Roles":[
         {
            "Ref":"yagel"
         }
      ]
   }
}
`


and i have these outputs:


`"Outputs": {
   "StackUUID":{
      "Value":{
         "Fn::Select":[
            0,
            {
               "Fn::Select":[
                  4,
                  {
                     "Fn::Split":[
                        "/",
                        {
                           "Ref":"AWS::StackId"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            33
         ]
      }
   }
}

I tried to upload this file and the error was unresolved reference to StackUUID,
The problem is that outputs are calculated in the end and therefore i can't use role policy with StackUUID..
Is there a way for me to define a variable with this calculation? or maybe to do concatenation
in a dynamic way in the policy name?
